# Error al abrir visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, windows

El problema que tengo es que cuando abro **visual studio 2015** me sale el siguiente error:

> "Se produjo una excepcion en el destino de la invocacion"

Me abre la pantalla de bienvenida pero no logra abrir el programa, probé instalar el 2017 e igual me ocurre lo mismo, probé abrir el 2010 y si lo pude abrir no se cual es el problema salio de un día para otro.

Si alguien por favor me puede ayudar u orientarme por donde puedo encontrar una solución estaría muy agradecido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has intentado reinstalar Microsoft ASP.NET como en esta pregunta?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750397/exception-has-been-thrown-by-a-target-of-invocation-when-starting-up-visual-st

Comment: trata de volver instalar los Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
es problema con la dll. https://www.microsoft.com/es-cl/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: Estoy con el mismo error, indagando en lo profundo de internete por lo visto es que el net framework de los cojones falla, es el encargado de ejecutar estas vainas en el entorno de microsoft, lo e eliminado e instalado el ultimo y sigue igual, tambien elimine TODOS los redistibutables para intalar el ultimo y tampoco va
Si das con algo dime, por que reiniciar el ordenador ... me da que uso notepad antes quue eso